# Create dynamic table with Add Update Delete options

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to asp.net so I dont know the best approach to deal following scenario.
I want to create a dynamic table like following which perform Add Update Delete -

```
Player SmartGoal Decision Thinking
ABC      10          10      9
PQR      7            9     10
```

next time table would be -

```
Player Decision   Learning
ABC      10          5      
PQR      7           9
```

I am using c#

I think we have to create databinding to control and control programmatically.

What control should I use?
What is the best approach for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GridView](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70) control.
Or for more advanced and neat stuff you probably want to try [telerik][2] controls (not free)
This all needs to be driven by a database.

Just search for two tutorials to get started: how to create a sql server database, and how to use GridView control.

if you need to display hierachical data you can try to use [ListView](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html) control:

Comment: I have already tried both the controls. For the Gridview or Listview I have to bind fileds like    <asp:TextBox ID="SmartGoal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SmartGoal") %>'></asp:TextBox>  But my field names gets changed all the time. 
However I tried to create controls dynamically in code behind file in which I spend two days. But I was not able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are fetching data from DB and binding to some control. I thinks the best approach for this to get the dataset from Database and bind to the gridview. You can find many example on net for bind sql datset on internet. Please let me know for any further clarification.

Thanks
Uttam

Comment: I tried it but how to bind them with different number of columns? The problem is name and number of column vary each time..

Comment: If possible provide some more details. Here i am placing one example where dynamic table is created at runtime

Answer (score 0):

One Approach is:
Get the column name from Database and add them to a Label.
like `lblColumn1.Text = colname1` & so on. Use loop.

Next step is to get the entries and add them to textbox/label again.
`similar coding`.
Forget not to use Try/catch for exceptions. You never know which column in DB isn't having values or null values.

For Edit/Add/Delete.
Add buttons before each each record to `delete and edit`
`add` button should be on top.

**No need to databind or anything like that.
**Basic knowledge of asp will do.

Comment: Can I grab dataset from code behind and iterate those data into aspx file? If yes then how can I iterate it in aspx file? I tried it but didnt work. Do you have any sample code for that?

Comment: But my number of columns not defined.. so I cant predict number of labels.

Comment: @Hiral, Generate it dynamically. `while(count of rows in DB)`

Comment: Thanks to reply vikbehal. I have done it with ListView programmatically

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are fetching data from DB and binding to some control. I thinks the best approach for this to get the dataset from Database and bind to the gridview. You can find many example on net for bind sql datset on internet. Please let me know for any further clarification.

If possible provide some more details. Here i am placing one example where dynamic table is created at runtime

Private Sub BuildSTX9Header()
        Dim dtTemp As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow

```
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("STXLocationID").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("SKU").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("SKU Description").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("MED").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("MSFSupportedProduct").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("Infor365 Product").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("SupportPlan").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("No.Users").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("SAM").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("LocationName").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("SerialNumber").ToString)
    dtTemp.Columns.Add(Me.GetLocalResourceObject("Phone").ToString)


    For i = 0 To dsData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        dr = dtTemp.NewRow()

        dr(0) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2)
        dr(1) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(3)
        dr(2) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(4)
        dr(3) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(5)
        dr(4) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(6)
        dr(5) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(7)
        dr(6) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(8)
        dr(7) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(9)
        dr(8) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(10)
        dr(9) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(11)
        dr(10) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(12)
        dr(11) = dsData.Tables(0).Rows(i)(13)
        dtTemp.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    gvLoadRuntime.DataSource = dtTemp
    gvLoadRuntime.DataBind()
    ViewState("RowCount") = dtTemp.Rows.Count
    ViewState("dvRuntimeData") = dtTemp
```

Thanks
Uttam